# when i compile my code i get th is error stating "checkbutton" not declared in this scope

Tags: arduino-uno

```
// After 2 seconds have passed, stop ignoring the button.
  // If the button is pressed, call the checkbutton function.
  if (millis() > ignore && digitalRead(0) == LOW)
  {
    checkbutton();
  }
}
// This function waits for the button to be released,
// then waits for it to be pressed to start the next run.
void checkbutton(){
  delay (50);  // Button pressed, debounce.
  while (digitalRead(0) == LOW) // While button is pressed,
  {}                            // do nothing while waiting.
  delay (50);                   // Button pressed, debounce.
  while (digitalRead(0) == HIGH)// While button is released,
  {}                            // do nothing while waiting.


  ignore = 2000 + millis();     // Set the now ignore time,
}                              // and return to the main loop.
```

Comment: Please update your sketch to add a `setup()` and `loop()` function, then add your code to it with proper formatting.

Comment: please do not be offended, but i downvoted your question because you posted a complete mess ... did you not look at what you posted? ... please format your code ... use the `{}` button to do the formatting ... also, please ask a question

Comment: You need to provide a fully functional code, not only a snippet of your code. That will not work alone. Also you need to include the complete error message, including the line number, where the error happened.

Comment: Are you using the Arduino IDE to compile? It will automatically add function prototypes to the top of your code. When you are using something else to compile, you need to declare every function above where you are using it

Answer (score 2):

You are using `checkbutton()` before you have told the program what `checkbutton()` is.

You need to move the whole method definition `void checkbutton(){ ... }` more to the top, i.e. in front of any call to it (`checkbutton();`).

Another option would be a [forward declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration), but I doubt it's widely used in Arduino projects.

Comment: @jsotola: that's true. I don't think this is widely used in Arduino projects. Anyway, I added that to the answer

Comment: The only reason it isn't widely used is because the IDE does it for you - invisibly. While that helps people just learning C and C++ to get something up and running quickly, they miss learning about forward declarations, which inevitably bites them when they move to another environment.